# Error ':android:transformKotlinClassesWithJillForDebug'. When building Android application written in Kotlin + LibGDX

Tags: android, gradle, build, libgdx, kotlin

I'm developing game on Kotlin using LibGDX framework. I have problem when building Android application. Desktop and IOS([moe-framework](https://github.com/multi-os-engine/multi-os-engine)) builds fine.

Here is full message:

```
Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task ':android:transformKotlinClassesWithJillForDebug'.
> File '/Users/maximternovtsi/bagel/android/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug.jar' specified for property 'inputJarFile' does not exist.
```

My `build.gradle` file:

```
 buildscript {
     repositories {
         mavenLocal()
         mavenCentral()
         maven {
             url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
         }
         jcenter()
     }
     dependencies {
         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
         classpath 'org.multi-os-engine:moe-gradle:1.3.6'
         classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.1.1"
     }
 }
 allprojects {
     apply plugin: "eclipse"
     apply plugin: "idea"
     version = '1.0'
     ext {
         appName = "Bagel"
         gdxVersion = '1.9.6'
     }
     repositories {
         mavenLocal()
         mavenCentral()
         maven {
             url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"
         }
         maven {
             url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
         }
     }
 }
 project(":desktop") {
     apply plugin: "kotlin"
     dependencies {
         compile project(":core")
         compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
         compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
         compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
         compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
     }
 }
 project(":android") {
     apply plugin: "android"
     apply plugin: "kotlin-android"
     configurations {
         natives
     }
     dependencies {
         compile project(":core")
         compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
         compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
         compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
     }
 }
 project(":core") {
     apply plugin: "kotlin"
     dependencies {
         compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
         compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
         compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
         compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.1"
         compile "com.badlogicgames.ashley:ashley:1.7.0"
         //        compile 'com.esotericsoftware:kryonet:2.22.0-RC1'
         //        compile 'io.netty:netty-all:4.1.13.Final-SNAPSHOT'
     }
 }
 project(":ios-moe") {
     apply plugin: "moe"
     configurations {
         natives
     }
     dependencies {
         compile project(":core")
         compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-moe:$gdxVersion"
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
         natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
     }
 }
 tasks.eclipse.doLast {
     delete ".project"
 }
```

Maybe i should post more code. I don't know what else can help you. Just write a comment and i will show you what you need. I've never faced problems like this. Google also didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, You need to update Kotlin version `1.1.1` to `1.1.51`

than add `kotlin-stdlib` artifact in android dependency tag.

```
compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.51"
```